# Integrate MS Dynamic CRM Form in Sitecore XP 9.3

Tags: mvc-forms, integration

What is the best approach to achieve below scenarios while integrating Dynamic CRM Form on a page in Sitecore XP 9.3?

1. Dynamic CRM Form should follow the same styles as Sitecore website. We already have few  Sitecore Form implementation on few pages. Do we need to check CSS class applied on various Sitecore Form fields and apply the same CSS class in all fields in Dynamic CRM Form HTML **OR** we need to write separate CSS in Dynamic CRM Form itself to match the CSS with Sitecore website?
2. Client side input fields error handling. For example if all fields are blank, we need to show mandatory input field error message next to each fields and a div section just above the form which will have all error message as a bullet list. Do we need to write custom error handling JavaScript(jQuery) code in Sitecore JS file on page load **OR** Dynamic CRM Form can take care of this?

Please note in this case we're not using any MS Dynamic CRM module. It's just a form script generated by MS Dynamic CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the styling and functionality of any third party generated script.

**Styling**

Getting the generated HTML to resemble your sitecore website might be as simple as removing the link to the 3rd party CSS file. However this will totally depend on how the site and associated global css has been put together.

It's likely however that the generated html does not exactly match that which is expected, or the sitecore website forms HTML uses its own classes. If this is the case you will need to write additional selectors to deal with any discrepancies.

If the generated HTML has any inline scripts, you will need to counter these (with more css) to match your own style.

**Scripting**

Updating the functionality of the form to introduce additional client side validation will certainly be possible, but this will come with additional risk. You need to fully understand what the code is doing before making changes, as this could lead to the form failing in some way. This  is often made more difficult because the 3rd party scripts are minified and/or obfuscated.

My suggestion would be to break down each task that you are trying to achieve and then ask a specific question related to that task. Each time including the all the details and source code that you have available, so as to better allow people to help